# Django queryset caching with exists() and values_list()

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, python-2.7, django-models

Let's say, I'm trying to change the name of all profiles whose name is `John` to `Mike`

```
queryset = Profile.objects.filter(name='John')
```

Method 1:

```
if queryset:
    queryset.update(name='Mike')
    logger.info(f'Updated the following profiles: {queryset.values_list('id', flat=True)}')
```

Method 2:

```
if queryset.exists():
    queryset.update(name='Mike')
    logger.info(f'Updated the following profiles: {queryset.values_list('id', flat=True)}')
```

QUESTION: What's the most efficient way to update all the fields with the name `John`, and log the records' ids that were updated?

Comment: It's the other way around: method 2 is more efficient. Method 1 fetches the entire queryset, method 2 doesn't.

Comment: The most efficient way is to not use `.exists()` and to also not test the truthy-ness of the queryset. Just call the update, if no rows match the queryset then it's basically the same as testing for existing rows anyway

Comment: @IainShelvington you brought an interesting point, and I apologize in advance, but what if I want to log all the profiles ids that were updated? I mean, I still need to evaluate the queryset, so I would think Method 1, now in this case, will be more efficient.

Comment: @Anthony in your example the call to `queryset.values_list` would call the DB again but there would be no rows with the name equal to "John" as all those rows were just updated

Comment: @IainShelvington Interesting, so running value_list will query again giving me no values. What would be the most efficient approach then to do the update but also log all the ids that were modified?

Comment: Added an answer

Answer (score 1):

In *Method 1*, calling `if queryset` evaluates the **entire queryset**.

In *Method 2*, using `queryset.exists()` makes a query, as does the `queryset.update(...)` call.

The most efficient method would be to skip the conditional `if` statement entirely, and just call `queryset.update(...)`. The return value of the call will include the amount of rows that were updated, which may be `0`.

To test the differences, we can use `django.db.connection` which will list all of the executed queries, and how long they took.

```py
from django.db import connection, reset_queries

from django.contrib.models import User


def method_1(queryset):
    if queryset:
        queryset.update(first_name="Mike")

def method_2(queryset):
    if queryset.exists():
        queryset.update(first_name="Mike")

def method_3(queryset):
    queryset.update(first_name="Mike")


>>> connection.queries == []  # empty to start
True

>>> method_1(User.objects.all())
>>> [query["time"] for query in connection.queries]
['0.051', '0.126']

>>> reset_queries()

>>> method_2(User.objects.all())
>>> [query["time"] for query in connection.queries]
['0.001', '0.125']

>>> reset_queries()

>>> method_3(User.objects.all())
>>> [query["time"] for query in connection.queries]
['0.122']
```

As you can see, `method_3` only uses a single query to perform the update, and is faster than the other methods.

Answer (score 1):

If you must get the ID of every updated Profile you should query this first as after you update the rows you will not be able to query this again. You can use the result of this to determine if you should run the update.

```
profile_ids_to_update = list(queryset.values_list('id', flat=True))
if profile_ids_to_update:
    queryset.update(name='Mike')
    logger.info(f'Updated the following profiles: {profile_ids_to_update}')
```

This will result in at most 2 queries, if there are no rows to update there will only be 1